# Oracle DB lock table use

Tags: oracle, transactions, locking, distributed, xa

Recently I had a task, according to which, I needed to have a specific lock functionality. The specific was due to:

> 1. Transaction that was updating
>      table was distributed, so I had no
>      controll over it,
> 2. During the day
>      thousands non blocking transactions
>      must be supported simultaniously,
>      lets call them 'general' operations,
> 3. Each 'general' operation updated rows on specific 'branch' ("LDN","NY","LA" ...),
> 4. Once a day there is a 'master'
>      operation for each branch, which happen spanteniously, on different branches,
>
>    1. During 'master' operation no
>         'general' operations on that branch can happen.
>    2. When 'master' operation start it
>         must wait for current 'general'
>         operation on the provided branch completion, 
>         which were in the system before 'master' operation arrived.
>    3. Durring 'master' processing on a specific branch, all other branches can be
>         updated.

In order to archive this, I created Oracle DB specific table

```
create table BRANCH_LOCK(
    BRANCH VARCHAR2(10),
    FLAG   VARCHAR2(1),
    CONSTRAINT "PK_BRANCH_LOCK" PRIMARY KEY ("BRANCH")
)
```

The following functionality for different operations was supported:

For 'general' operations:

> ```
> 1. In the same XA transaction each operation locks BRANCH_LOCK table 
>    in SHARE mode,
> 2. After locking it checks FLAG, on updated branch,
>   1. If flag is 'Y', that means that currently 'master' 
>       operation is in progess, so  Exception is thrown, 
>      and no further processing is done;
>   2. If flag is 'N' than everything is OK, and general processing is done;
> ```

For 'master' operation:

> 1. When 'master' operation comes I start separate transaction which:
>
>    1. Lock BRANCH_LOCK table in EXCLUSIVE mode, which transaction can not acquire while          there is SHARE mode LOCK on this table in  a different transaction (This way, I guarantee that 'master' operation would start after all current 'general' operation finish, although it waits for transactions on all branches
>         to finish, not only specified one),
>    2. Sets flag for the branch to 'Y'
>         (This way, I guarantee that there would be no 'general' transactions while 'master'
>         operation processing),
> 2. In incoming transaction I change a Flag in the table to 'N', so after
>      it commits BRANCH_LOG table will have
>      appropriate value in FLAG column, and system would
>      be able to process 'general'
>      operations again.

This has not gone in production yet, So I wonder is there a better solution for this,
and are there any more drawbacks besides described one?

Some updates, which I did not mention:

1. 'Master' operation works on results of 'general' operations, So it is vital, that no 'general' operation get lost, durring the 'master' processing, so this why current 'general' operation must finish, before master operation start processing.
2. Multiple 'general' operations on the same branch happen every second, arround 3'000 operations per second,
3. Only one 'master' operation for the branch can happen, multiple 'master' operations on different branches can be processed at the same time.

Comment: I'm not clear on your point (1).  What does it being distributed have to do with whether you can control it?  Also, is this referring to the general or master operation?

Comment: You imply, but don't state outright, that it is OK for multiple general operations on the same branch to work at once.  Is that correct?

Comment: Regarding comments.
Regarding point 1 all the operations general and master are distributed, so I don't know when transaction starts, and when will it be commited, or rolledback, over this points in time I have no control.
Regarding general operations, there must be 3'000 oper per sec on the same branch supported, so yes, there are multiple operations at the same time for one branch, happening simultaniously.

Answer (score 2):

Anton,
why exactly do you need to manually lock the table[s]? Normally there is no need to do such. When the master operation you describe starts, it get's a read consistent view of the data that is committed at the start of that master transaction. The general transactions can continue to work and the master transaction you describe will not see the changes, until it starts a new transaction.

Comment: This is a business requierement, no general operation should be processed durring 'master' operation, and there must be no current 'general' operations when 'master' operation starts, otherwise we get data inconsitency. Also 'master' operation requires 1'000 times more time then general one.

Comment: Anton, is all data managed by the oracle database? or is data also managed on files? If only managed by the oracle database there should not be a problem because of the read consistent view. If data that should be consistent with the database is also outside the database, I would seriously rethink that part.

Comment: All information is stored in Oracle DB. 
I don't think that consistency works here, because master operation must process changes made by general operations durring the day, and it is important, that no 'general' operation get lost. So if there are uncommited changes made by current 'general' operations, than they would not be seen by master operation, and there for lost in master process, which is not acceptable. So consistency does not work here.

Comment: I can see that missing updates is no fun. For this is my next question: what happen to the transactions that are filed after the master process completes and releases the lock? I can imagine that the app has some way to recognize the new transactions? If that is based on time, you will search for new tx, created after the start date of the last master run. If that is the case, you can use the normal read consistent view if you ask me.

Comment: I thought, that what if 'general' and 'master' transaction would modify the same row? One would set let's say 5 in a NUMBER row, the other would set 10. What would be the outcome, and which update will be lost? From business point of view guessing is not acceptable. And system must guarantee that nothing is lost. So consistency read is not really an option from my point of view. Also business would get complains from it's customers of postponed updates, this is also unacceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than build my own lock table, I think I'd try to use Oracle's locking package [DBMS_LOCK.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lock.htm#sthref3240)

It's more efficient than using DML to do locks, and is what Oracle uses internally to perform enqueue locking.

Comment: OK, I am not a DBA actually, I am a developer, so I did not know of this ability, I'll take a look at it, Thanks.

Comment: Your DBA will likely need to grant you permission to execute this package.

Answer (score 0):

What are the table volumes.

I'd consider having the master operation start like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE do_master (in_branch IN VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
  SELECT ...
  BULK COLLECT INTO
  FROM ...
  WHERE branch = in_branch
  FOR UPDATE OF branch;
  ...
END do_master;
```

That would use standard Oracle locking to ensure that the do_master waits until outstanding general transactions locking those branches complete, then the locks are taken by do_master stopping any other general updates until it commits. Then those general updates resume.

But if the volumes are big, then that SELECT...FOR UPDATE could be very large. That's when I'd consider a DBMS_LOCK solution.

Comment: Yes volumes are big, it is financial product, and have data duplicated for almostly each day, with millions of records in there. Although we have such kind of lock in DB, which contains part of the PK of changed record, without a date. 
But there is a problem however, what if new transaction creates new record in this branch, this record would not be seen by provided query. So this update will be lost. Also, from my point of view, it is better to set a flag in one record in one table, than to lock 1'000'000 records at another.